# Logging request and response for Spring mvc Service

Tags: spring, logging, service

1. hi All ,  i Have to log all the request , response , Exception ,
   Errors for my Spring  services. i had searched about the
   interceptors , filters , logging filters ,  Spring interceptors :
   HandlerInterceptorAdapter logger filters : 
   AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java and its sub classes 
   (http://www.javawebdevelop.com/1704067/), 
   CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.java filters : LoggerFilter.

   can any body its difference,  and the best approach to do so i am
   confused or i need to find out the third party library to do this
   ?..

Answer (score 0):

[Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) is a java based logging utility with easy integration with Spring MVC. Log4j comes with different logging levels to allow for appropriate logging in correspondence to the development environment.

Log4j 2 is the successor to log4j and has better performance as compared to its predecessor.

Kindly refer the following link for an integration of spring MVC + Log4j
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/how-to-use-log4j-in-spring-mvc

Edit: As mentioned in comment , PFB the code for logging both request and response.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ResponseLoggerAspect {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("requestResponseLogger");
ExclusionStrategy excludeJsonAnnotation = new JsonIgnoreAnnotationExclusionStrategy();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(excludeJsonAnnotation).create();

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void controller() {}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
public void method() {}

@Pointcut("execution(@com.company.annotation.AddLog * *(..))")
public void Loggable() {}

//This will be caught for only those controller method where @AddLog annotation is written
@Before("Loggable()")
public void printRequestLog(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    try {
        Object[] argsList = joinPoint.getArgs();
        String str = "[";
        for(Object arg : argsList) {
            if(arg instanceof Object[]) {
                str += Arrays.toString((Object[])arg) + ", ";
            } else {
                str += String.valueOf(arg) + ", ";
            }
        }
        str += "]";
        logger.info("Request args for " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " are : " + str);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.info("Unable to log request args", ex);
    }
}

//This will be called for all controller methods after returning 
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "controller() && method()", returning="result")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint , Object result)  {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        logger.info("Response sent by " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " are : " + gson.toJson(result));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Returned result cant be converted in JSON " , ex);
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info("elapsed time : " + (end - start));
}
```

}

Comment: Please see the edit above. I hope I have answered your query.

Answer (score 0):

I used AOP for something similar in one project. I had to write a class like this:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class RequestMonitor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestMonitor.class);

    @Around("@annotation(org.example.ToBeLogged)")
    public Object wrap(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        logger.info("Before controller method " + pjp.getSignature().getName() + ". Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
        logger.info("Controller method " + pjp.getSignature().getName() + " execution successful");

        return retVal;
    }
}
```